# Слитно или раздельно писать "неограничиваемые"?

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, что здесь прилагательное, образованное от переходного глагола несовершенного вида (по Розенталю) и, поскольку нет пояснительного слова в творительном падеже, надо писать слитно. Но не уверена.

…и этим обнажал не ограничиваемые противоречия технологической и конструкторской служб завода...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном вами примере необходимо слитное написание. Нет противопоставления, нет пояснительного слова в творительном падеже. Можно заменить синонимом: бесконечные, вечные.

Answer (score 2):

Да, здесь слитное написание, нет зависимого слова в Т.п.

Comment: Vera, пишите чуть подробнее, ваши ответы регулярно попадают в "сомнительные" - на перепроверку другими пользователями. Идеально писать так, чтобы понять ответ можно было не читая вопрос. А так как Вы - это для комментариев, где сохраняется последовательность диалога. Я так понимаю политику ресурса. Если ошибаюсь, пусть поправят.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Я думала, что форма ответа свободная. Автор вопроса фактически ответил на него, а я подтвердила правильность решения. Конечно, можно привести всё правило целиком, но тогда это материал на полстраницы.  Скорее всего, система задает объем ответа, но не его качество. Тогда надо знать минимальный объем - допустим, не менее 200 знаков.

Answer (score 2):

> Слитно или раздельно писать “неограничиваемые”?

**И не слитно, и не раздельно.** Слово это вообще нужно выкинуть, предложение перестроить.

**P.S.**

Если приведёте предложение полностью, постараюсь что-нибудь придумать.